# Managing project Clearcase

Tags: cvs, clearcase

Language : Java
IDE :Eclipse
CVS (version control system)
ClearCase (Development & Integration Streams)

We have recently completed our project.
Now, we have two different clients and has to manage the existing project to cater their needs.

We are thinking of creating three integration streams

one forexisting client support
one for client 2
one for client 3
..

However we are unsure of how do we manage the Project in CVS.

Though braching in CVS is an option .However we are dreading  the brach -> root merging issues as the file system will be common  in all the branches and different developers can work on the same file in different branches.

Could you please suggest how do go about this scenario?.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Integration  streams are a good option with ClearCase because you can deliver between them, and you can rebase any baseline on them (not just a baseline from the *parent* stream=

You could then follow the page "[Working with CVS and Clearcase](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/dmndhelp/v7r0mx/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.wbit.help.team.doc/topics/cshare.html)", and use ClearCase for those merge, before mirroring the result of those merge back in CVS.